# select GROUP_CONCAT in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I have two tables:

table1:

```
id email
1  john@gmail.com
2  doe@gmail.com
```

table2:

```
userid   key         value
1        firstname   john
1        phone       112233
2        firstname   doe
2        phone       223344
```

This is mysql query without condition:

```
SELECT a.*,
b.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(b.key),
GROUP_CONCAT(b.value)
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.userid
```

This is result:

```
array(
[id] => 1
[email] => john@gmail.com
[userid] => 1
[key] => firstname,phone
[value] => john,112233
)
array(
[id] => 2
[email] => doe@gmail.com
[userid] => 2
[key] => firstname,phone
[value] => doe,223344
)
```

This is mysql query with condition:

```
SELECT a.*,
b.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(b.key),
GROUP_CONCAT(b.value)
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.userid
WHERE b.key = "firstname"
  AND b.value LIKE '%jo%'
```

And this is result:

```
array(
[id] => 1
[email] => john@gmail.com
[userid] => 1
[key] => firstname
[value] => john
)
```

But I want this:

```
array(
[id] => 1
[email] => john@gmail.com
[userid] => 1
[key] => firstname,phone
[value] => john,112233
)
```

There any way to do this? thank for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your queries are lacking the `GROUP BY` clause to get a row per user. Then use a `HAVING` clause to make sure the aggregated row includes a **firstname** `'%jo%'`:

```
SELECT a.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(b.key),
       GROUP_CONCAT(b.value)
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.userid
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING sum(b.key = 'firstname'
           AND b.value LIKE '%jo%') > 0;
```

true results in 1, false in 0 in MySQL. So checking whether the sum is greater than zero means checking whether the condition is true at least once.

Comment: Just one suggestion: `SELECT *` after `GROUP BY` clause is not recommended.

Comment: @Shidersz: Thank you, you are right. `select a.*` is okay and valid SQL, because `a.id` is supposedly the table's key, so `a.*` is functionally dependent on `group by a.id`, but `b.*` isn't and can lead to arbitrarily picked values. I've edited my answer accordingly and removed `b.*` from the select list.